# Reduce whitespace between words in section headings

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, titles

I have a section title that must fit onto a single line, and it is maybe a few mm off from fitting. If I can figure out a way to reduce the amount of whitespace *between each word* in the section title, it will be fine (see below for an illustration).

But for other reasons, I cannot reduce this space **globally** (even for all section titles). I just want to reduce space for this **one section title**.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If it helps, I am already using `titlesec`.

***Illustration:*** Right now, the section title looks like this (spacing is exaggerated for illustration purposes):

```
5.1   Here   is   my   section   title
```

I want it to look like this:

```
5.1 Here is my section title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a once-off hack, maybe just change the spacing, eg

```
\section{\spaceskip2pt Here is my section title}
```

or

```
\section{Here\thinspace is\thinspace my\thinspace section\thinspace title}
```

but don't forget to add the unqualified title as the ToC option, eg

```
\section[Here is my section title]{\spaceskip2pt Here is my section title}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Was not aware of \spaceskip, this is exactly what I was looking for.